# Expose console app info through web browser in .Net core 3.1

Tags: c#, console-application, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a heavy console app that executes several threads that read, perform calculations and write to outputs in different scenarios. Now I'm triying to simply create a way for everyone to be able to access to the data (real-time or near-real-time) through a web browser using either localhost or http/https.

I've tried following [this resource](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/what-are-dotnet-worker-services) as well as [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62707093/dotnet-core-3-1-console-app-hosting-optional-web-api-for-control). I've actually looked around and found about self  hosting, but I don't really know how to implement it in a simple manner.

for brevity's sake, I add a very simple example of a console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int x = 0;
        public static int y = 0;
        public static int z = 0;
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<String, int> ValuesDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Function that updates the values in the dictionary
            Thread createInputFileThread = new Thread(() => UpdateDictionaryThreadFunction(10000));
            createInputFileThread.Start();

            //How to start a simple web host here!
        }

        public static void UpdateDictionaryThreadFunction(int refreshTime)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(refreshTime);
                if (x < 100000 && y < 100000 && z < 100000)
                {
                    ValuesDictionary.AddOrUpdate("ValueX", x, (key, oldValue) => oldValue + 1);
                    ValuesDictionary.AddOrUpdate("ValueY", y, (key, oldValue) => oldValue + 2);
                    ValuesDictionary.AddOrUpdate("ValueZ", z, (key, oldValue) => oldValue + 3);
                }
                else
                {
                    ValuesDictionary.AddOrUpdate("ValueX", x, (key, oldValue) => 0);
                    ValuesDictionary.AddOrUpdate("ValueY", y, (key, oldValue) => 0);
                    ValuesDictionary.AddOrUpdate("ValueZ", z, (key, oldValue) => 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The goal here would be to access the data in the ValuesDictionary through something like `localhost:someport` or `http://somename:someport` and obtain something like: (The values would be refreshed every x seconds)

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ValueX | 34 |
| ValueY | 42 |
| ValueZ | 42 |

Comment: The two links aren't directly related to what you want to do. A worker service is useful if you want to create a service/daemon. It's quite likely you *do* want to do something like this, and replace the thread that calls `UpdateDictionaryThreadFunction`, but that doesn't help when to create a web app. If you check the code generated by `dotnet new web` you can see that it's possible to create a minimal *console* application listening to for eg GET that returns raw string responses. Writing HTML like that is hard and ugly though

Comment: I would discouple the app from the console and make it a service. You can couple that to different user interfaces like the console or an asp.net web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use .net core.. you want a console app that serves TCP-IP on some port.. a minimal solution I would say is to link Kestrel to your console app, assign the request-receiver event and launch it on your port.. to repeatedly refresh the client you can use client side local JS with a timer. Your server can generate the usual HTML incorporating that JS part for the client's browser.

Example of using Kestrel in a Console app:

https://jonhilton.net/2016/07/18/your-first-net-core-web-application-using-nothing-but-the-command-line/

NOTE: this is an old fashioned "quick solution". Also with Kestrel, it is better to structure your app first, as a reporting Service, independent of the platform choices. You could then "plugin" that code in any platform you may need to use in the future (SignalR, Blazor, ASP, Azure etc)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) for this kind of requirements

Comment: SignalR works on an already existing web infrastructure, to push data to clients. The question is how to add a simple web UI - how to add that web infrastructure