# .Net core 3.1 Simple View returning internal server error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, console-application

Recently I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66988433/expose-console-app-info-through-web-browser-in-net-core-3-1) about exposing a console app through a web browser. I received a very [helpful answer](https://jonhilton.net/2016/07/18/your-first-net-core-web-application-using-nothing-but-the-command-line/) and followed the instructions in the [link](https://jonhilton.net/2016/07/27/how-to-add-mvc-to-your-asp-net-core-web-application/) provided, but then I can't seem to display a simple view, even when returning OK works fine:

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Controller.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("home/Index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //return Ok("Hello from a controller");   //THIS WORKS 

        IndexModel data = new IndexModel();         //THIS RETURNS INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500
        data.Title = "THIS";
        data.Message = "MESSAGE";
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

The Model and index:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

@page
@model ConsoleApp1.Views.Home.IndexModel
@{
}
<div>
    <p>@Model.Title</p>
    <p>@Model.Message</p>
</div>
```

This is the error i get when trying to display the view
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that you are create a `asp.net-core-3.1 mvc` project.

Your project structure should look like this:

[image]

Then change your `Startup` to:

```
 public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
     
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your `project.csproj`.Change it to(notice that it's `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"`) :

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext />
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Sorry, But I dindn't create an MVC project, I made a console application, and then made it to be able to host on a port so I could comunicate with it. I don't have taht same structure and my project has  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"> because it IS a console app

Comment: I know this is the case, but you can change it to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` to make it work

Answer (score 0):

At first view, I don't see a default routing configuration

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

My suggestion is to add a custom exception middleware

```
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
```

and the custom exception handler

```
 public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //inspect the exception here
        }
    }
```

and after that debug and inspect where and what kind of exception you are receiving after a request is submitted.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I'm getting this error The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

Comment: Well, this means that you don't have an `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` file. When returning this `return View(data);` the MVC engine searcher for  `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` to render the view. Also I would test what happens if you remove this `[Route("home/Index")]` from the `HomeController/Index`. I'm not sure that you need attribute routing after you added default routes.